# How to search for a null value using path range index?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I've defined a path range index for a field and it might happen that the field value is null. The object stored in Marklogic is like:

> {"the": {"path": {"to": {"field": null} } } }

I've tried the query

> cts:path-range-query("/the/path/to/field", "=", json:null())

and it doesn't return any result. If, instead I define a new value for when the field is null and create an index just for this case, the search return results.

New document:

> {"the": {"path": {"to": {"field": null, "fieldIsNull": true} } } }

New query:

> cts:path-range-query("/the/path/to/fieldIsNull", "=", "true")

how can I search for null values using a path range index without resorting to a new index?

I'm using Marklogic 9.0-4.

Comment: @brunovianarezende-- When you say null values. By that you mean you want to return the nodes which are having empty values ??

Comment: no, I'm referring to values that are really null. I've updated the question to make it clear.

Comment: What is the datatype of your path index? xs:string?

Comment: yes, it is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this in Server-Side JavaScript:

```
cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("field", null)
```

Which is written like this in XQuery:

```
cts:json-property-value-query("Output", null-node {})
```

Did you try replacing `json:null()` with `null-node{}` in your path range query?

HTH!

Comment: I just tried to use null-node {} and it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, come to think of it, your path range index enforces a datatype, making it difficult to pinpoint `null` exactly. You can get close with something like `cts:not-query(cts:path-range-query("Output", '>=', ''))`, but that will also match docs missing the property, and properties with an empty array. `cts:json-property-value-query()` is really the only way to match against `null` directly.

Comment: can you make this an answer? I think it is good enough to know that it can't be done by using a path range index. However, the workaround you provided has a drawback: it won't work like the boolean index in the case we have multiple items reached by the path. Example: in {"key": [{"value": "anything", "isNull": "false"}, {"value": null, "isNull": "true"}]} the query `cts:path-range-query("/key/isNull", '=', 'true')` will return a result, while `cts:not-query(cts:path-range-query("/key/value", '>=', ''))` won't.

Comment: Have you tried using cts:json-property-value-query? It doesn't rely on range indexes, and saves you from adding the isNull property..

Comment: yes, I tried and it suffers from the same problem I cited in my other comment.

Comment: to give you a bit more of context, I'm not actually using cts:search, instead I'm using java-search-api, that uses search:search. We try to use path range indexes to make it possible to have precise estimates of the results, this is needed because java search api always do unfiltered searches. If we don't have precise estimates, pagination might be broken and customer will complain.

Comment: The value-query with null-node will be accurate in unfiltered conditions too. Easy to check with a cts:search with 'unfiltered' flag.

Comment: true, but it won't do the other thing I pointed: the document `{"key": [{"value": "anything", "isNull": "false"}, {"value": null, "isNull": "true"}]}` won't be a match for the query  `cts:not-query(cts:path-range-query("/key/value", '>=', ''))` while it will be for `cts:path-range-query("/key/isNull", '=', 'true')`

Comment: I was talking about `cts:json-property-value-query`, not the `cts:path-range-query` (with or without `cts:not-query`)

Answer (score 0):

In my view, this is where MarkLogic really blew it incorporating JSON.  XQuery and XML don't have NULL values, and in fact nulls are a huge problem that one is blissfully free of when using XML and XQuery. But now not only do you have actual nulls, you have a NullNode type. Which gives you this anomalous behavior:

```js
let b=null
b ? 'true' : 'false'  // returns false 

let a=new NullNode()
a ? 'true' : 'false'  // returns true
```

This makes it way more complicated to deal with data containing 'null,' as if that weren't a total hassle to begin with!